# find average of all the pixels using cli

Tags: image, imagemagick

Is there a cli way of getting the average value of all the pixels in an image

for example - if i have an all black image, I would want to type:

```
   *cmd* black-img.jpg
```

and the output will be `0` in the shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, this is simple:

```
convert  image.jpg  -scale 1x1\!  txt:-
```

The command uses ImageMagick's `convert` to enforce scaling of the input image to a size 1x1 pixels. Output will be something like this for an 8-bit RGBA image:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,srgba
0,0: (151,161,212, 92)  #97A1D45C  srgba(151,161,212,0.361928)
```

or this for an 8-bit sRGB image:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,srgb
0,0: (229,226,229)  #E5E2E5  srgb(229,226,229)
```

It represents the color value of the single-pixel image that was produced:

- `0,0:` are the coordinates of this pixel: 1st row in 1st column.
- `(151,161,212, 92)` represent the  **R** ed, **G** reen, **B** lue and  **A** lpha values of the RGBA pixel.
- `(229,226,229)` represent the **R** ed, **G** reen and  **B** lue values of the sRGB pixel.
- `#97A1D45C` and `#E5E2E5` are the respective hex values.

Now it's your own job to compute this output into '*a `'0'` in the shell'* if it is a black pixel.  :-)

Comment: thats very neat! can you can first turn it to grayscale so you don't have to average them?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the original poster seems to want not the 3 or 4 *color* channel values when he asks about *'getting the average value of all the pixels in an image'*... he wants one single value that can be derived by converting the image to grayscale first:

```
convert  image.jpg  -colorspace gray  -scale 1x1\!  txt:-
```

Sample output for the same 8-bit RGBA (with Alpha channel) image as in the other answer:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,graya
0,0: (119,119,119, 92)  #7777775C  graya(119,119,119,0.361928)
```

Output for the 8-bit sRGB image (without Alpha channel) from before:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,gray
0,0: (221,221,221)  #DDDDDD  gray(221,221,221)
```